# How to match all paths between two nodes with a relationship property filter?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to perform a query to retrieve all paths between two nodes a and b in which all the paths there is a relationship property fulfilled.

I have tried in many ways but I am not able to success.

```sql
MATCH p=(o{value:"a"})-[r*]-(x{value:"b"}) 
WHERE has(r.property) AND r.property="foo" 
RETURN p
```

I have changed the relationship part to `[r*..]` and many other options but not working.

The function `shortestpath` does not help me because I want not only the shortest but all the possibilities.

Can someone help me or tell me which is the error in the query?

Answer (score 9):

What you're looking for is the `ALL` predicate on the relationships collection of the path :

```
MATCH p=(o{value:"a"})-[r*]-(x{value:"b"})
WHERE ALL(x IN rels(p) WHERE x.property = "foo")
RETURN p
```

And please use labels !

Comment: I have tried MATCH p=(o{value:"a"})-[r*]-(x{value:"b"})
WHERE ALL(r IN rels(p) WHERE r.property = "foo")
RETURN p and still not working but neo4j takes more than 2 min and crashes. Is it normal or just that the graph is so big that takes so much times? Thanks!

Comment: As Christophe suggested, you should be adding labels to your nodes, types to your relationships, and indexes and/or constraints to speed up this query, as well as future queries. As written, this query is scanning all nodes in your db for those with values "a" and "b" (because you didn't use node labels and you can't take advantage of indexes or unique constraints without them), then finding every possible path in the db between them, then filtering. As written it's an insane query on the large db, so it's not surprising it would crash. Add more context, and you may get it lightning fast.

Comment: The problem is that despite I have indexes I cant use them since this query will be performed many times and I cant know to which node type the value belongs too (it might be the case that has two labels for the same value). The idea is to get all paths within a small subgraph (to query this subgraph does not take more than 1 sec). Thus, can I perform this query again after retrieving the subgraph first? MATCH (o)-[r]-(x) 
WHERE "foo" in r.property
RETURN * and now search for all paths between two nodes within the results of this query. Thank you!

Comment: @ddomingo I have the same problem. But my problem is simpler. I want path consisting only one type of nodes. I have indexed the nodes with the selecting property. "value" as in this query. Still it takes time when I try to get paths without giving directions. When I give a direction it works fast, but the results are incomplete. Do you have any idea?

Comment: is `[r*]` some shorthand for "any relationship"? Or is is a regex type match on any relationship called `r~something` ?

Comment: @dcsan the [r*] means indefinite depth. the fact we don't specify a relationship type means "any type"

Answer (score 0):

Could you add the property on the relation/edge?

`()-[r:label{property:"foo"}]->()`

That would force an edge with a value for `foo` property.
I'm not a neo4j expert but interested why this would not work.
Maybe you can post a mini-sample of the data for people to test it out with.